# Software to trim every ID3 fields of my mp3

Tags: gratis, music, mp3, id3

Many of my mp3s have ID3 fields that contain spaces at the beginning or at the end of the field. I'm looking for an application that:

- can trim (= remove start and end spaces) every ID3 field of each mp3 in the folder(s) I select
- walk the sub-folders recursively, i.e. not just take the mp3s located at the root of the folder
- has a GUI
- works on Windows, Linux or Mac OS
- is free or non-free

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/).  Mp3tag has a [replace with regular expression](http://help.mp3tag.de/options_format.html#regexp) action that will allow you to remove spaces in any tag field you want.

Your requirements:

- With some knowledge of regular expressions, you can trim spaces from the beginning and end of any ID3 field you want.
- Has the option of looking in all subfolders of a selected folder
- Has a GUI
- Gratis, runs on Windows

To trim spaces (beginning and end of all tags), use the action (thanks Izzy!):

[image]

Comment: Hint on a regexp: `^\s+(.*)\s+$` replace by "$1" (or "\1", depending on what the application uses for back-references). If you also want to catch those having spaces only in front *or* in the end (the above only catches those having both): `^\s+(.*)$` for the former, `^(.*)\s+$` for the latter.

Comment: @Izzy and Ben: Awesome, it works perfectly. I used `$1` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, this did not work for me. I used `_TAG`: `^\s+`-> "" and `_TAG`: `\s+$` -> "", which worked fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

[Puddletag](http://puddletag.sourceforge.net/index.html) is solution I'm using on Ubuntu. Puddletag generally looking is very similar to [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) available on windows platform.

[image: puddletag main scrren]

Requested functions:

- Trimming can be done using function Trim Whitespace (I don’t use this
  function personally since i do rename all files using my specific
  pattern)
- Folders can be added recursively
- GUI available
- Free of charge and open-source works on Ubuntu, Fedora, can be
  downloaded as deb or source  code, and  included in Ubuntu
  repositories

Beside requested functions there are few other I consider very useful such as auto numbering, remove duplicate values, remove all except chosen value, update fields from tag, sort values, import and export artwork, scripting functions (RegEx) and one I like most tagging audio files using web based Tag Sources like MusicBrainz, Discogs, Amazon, FreeDB, AcoustID. Its even possible to use Mp3tag’s Tag Sources but that one I never tested.

Answer (score 2):

## [MP3diags](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/140_main_window_tools.html)

I have seen the feature to remove whitespace in MP3diags but don't ask me which column it was. This program detects a myriad of errors and you could easily spend some days to fix them all.

It's free and [available for all major platforms](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/010_getting_the_program.html#binWindows)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Jaikoz Music Tagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz) has an inbuilt task specifically for this called **Remove WhiteSpace**, it also has a task called **Remove Widespace** that finds instances of multiple spaces together in the middle of text and reduces it down to one.

In this screenshot the first **Album Artist** value has both leading and trailing whitespace, and Jaikoz helpfully highlights this in pink, selecting the field and then choosing **Edit:Remove Whitespace** removes these. Of course you can select all fields and fix all fields in one go if you want.

There are also two spaces between *Sonic* and *Youth*, selecting **Remove Widespace** would reduce this to one.

Jaikoz works on OSX, Windows and Mac.

[image: Showing Remove Whitespace].

Disclaimer: I am the Jaikoz developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a rule in bliss to do this for you, so bliss trims all fields of a given type, for all albums:

Click the settings cog and enable the Tags rule:

[image: Enable the tags rule]

Now enable the trim rule, selecting the fields you'd like trimmed:

[image: Choose which fields you'd like trimmed of whitespace]

Finally, click "Apply rules" at the bottom of the page.

Disclaimer: I am the programmer and founder of the bliss project.